# centering website using header tag

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to know if it is possible to center a website header which has not been placed into divisions, but has been placed in the `header` tag.

It's code goes something like this:

```
 <header>
    <div class="top">
    </div>
    <div class="image">
    </div>
    </header>
```

The CSS goes something like this:

```
header
{
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.top
{
width: 30%;
background: yellow;
float:left;
padding: 2.5%
}

.image
{
width: 45%;
background: black;
float: left;
}
```

I want the contents inside the header to be centered in origanal size as well as when the website is being used in a smaller resolution (i.e. mobile).

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`.

The elements will then be inline. When adding a `text-align: center` to the header will make them center inside it.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.top, .image {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
.top {
  width: 30%;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 2.5%
}
.image {
  width: 45%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="top">t</div>
  <div class="image">i</div>
</header>
```